# How do I remove the double border on this table?

Tags: html, css

I am working on the HTML and CSS and I get this result which is not perfect:

[image]

I've created a fiddle with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/GParb/

But the borders of the table seem to not match the borders of the desired screen shot. How can I make the layout look more like the original mockup and remove the double borders on the table?

[image]

Here is the CSS and HTML code I have for the table:

CSS

```
table{ width:100%; text:align:center;border:1px solid #00F; font-size:12px;}
th{background:#EEE;width:auto; text-align:center; padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #00F;}
td{width:auto; text-align:center; padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #00F;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #EEE;}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/0b2bdf4f-c293-418b-a082-ef986eb94148">pelle</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/0b2bdf4f-c293-418b-a082-ef986eb94148">pelle@example</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/0b2bdf4f-c293-418b-a082-ef986eb94148"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/21153522-6544-4368-875a-753f4154ff9d">niklas</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/21153522-6544-4368-875a-753f4154ff9d">niklas</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/21153522-6544-4368-875a-753f4154ff9d"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/27053a2e-3742-4046-b876-87940c35b5bc">martin</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/27053a2e-3742-4046-b876-87940c35b5bc">martin</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/27053a2e-3742-4046-b876-87940c35b5bc"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/5e1947de-1185-44bb-a9f5-170df342124b">henrik</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/5e1947de-1185-44bb-a9f5-170df342124b">henrik</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/5e1947de-1185-44bb-a9f5-170df342124b"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/61a11f6e-e3bf-4d07-b05a-f7c3ecf0377f">niklasro@gmail.com</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/61a11f6e-e3bf-4d07-b05a-f7c3ecf0377f">niklasro@gmail.com</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/61a11f6e-e3bf-4d07-b05a-f7c3ecf0377f"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/83f96511-550e-4df0-bb77-e569fc0be2bc">marc</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/83f96511-550e-4df0-bb77-e569fc0be2bc">marc</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/83f96511-550e-4df0-bb77-e569fc0be2bc"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/95072cd9-749c-42e8-8c11-553def704f62">lukas</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/95072cd9-749c-42e8-8c11-553def704f62">lukas</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/95072cd9-749c-42e8-8c11-553def704f62"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/aa2d4b43-1f11-448b-bff1-0d4152c40735">rms</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/aa2d4b43-1f11-448b-bff1-0d4152c40735">rms</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/aa2d4b43-1f11-448b-bff1-0d4152c40735"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/c043d631-10e6-4b58-9a0f-6563199d42f7">kalle</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/c043d631-10e6-4b58-9a0f-6563199d42f7">kalle@example</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/c043d631-10e6-4b58-9a0f-6563199d42f7"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/f6e53781-4574-4d96-b900-204eaad6e662">blahonga</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="/admin/account/f6e53781-4574-4d96-b900-204eaad6e662">097097</a>       </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/editaccount/f6e53781-4574-4d96-b900-204eaad6e662"><img src="/images/edit.gif"></a><img src="/images/save.gif"><img src="/images/unlocked.gif"><img src="/images/locked.gif"> </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add the `border-collapse:collapse;` to the table css selector. This will eliminate that nested border look. Also, your `Text:align:center;` should really be `text-align:center;`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GParb/1/

CSS

```
table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #00F;
    font-size:12px;
    }
```

Unlike the `cellspacing="0"` as suggested below, this answer will collapse the borders to not be a 3D effect, just like what the OP asked for.

Comparison fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GParb/7/

Comment: simple and useful :)

Answer (score 5):

### **How do I remove the double border on this table?**

**1 . To remove the double-border look of a table**

Just edit your *table tag* as following:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="1"> ...</table>
```

To give color to the borders add : `bordercolor="#00F"`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GParb/3/)

But **cellpadding, cellspacing,border etc of a table are Deprecated Attributes**.Instead you can use the **CSS styles** equivalent to the above from the following table:

[image: Table styles]

---

**2 . To remove the double-border look of a table and to obtain the exact output as the image shown in the question**

*Best solution* : Use `border-collapse:collapse;` for the `<table>` element.

Comment: this still creates a 3d looking border... OP wanted a hairline around the edges.

Comment: @Phlume my answer was just to solve the problem mentioned in the title **How do I remove the double border on this table?** .I have now added more details to my answer.Check it

Comment: maybe "lead" with best solution... which was already stated previously so as to not confuse??

Answer (score 0):

Go the source code of that markup you like, select "View Page Source", copy the code, paste it and then style it and make it original yourself. You don't want to be too close to other peoples designs anyways.

Comment: A good option for altering something you know, but in this case the author didn't know what to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a little bit on your fiddle with `border-collapse:collapse`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GParb/8/)

hope it help